# Proof that either one of two expressions is always irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

I have these two terms:

$$b+a\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}$$
$$a-b\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}$$

---

The requirements are: $x,y\in\mathbb{Z};a,b,\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q};c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. So basically, x & y are whole numbers, a & b are irrational numbers, and c & d are real numbers. And also the whole term $\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}$ is definitely also irrational.

---

*Based on those conditions I want to try to **prove that one of the two terms mentioned above is definitely irrational** no matter which values the variables take on. If this is not true I would like to see a counterexample or any other kind of proof falsifying the claim.*

---

I have already tried to algebraically manipulate the term to find a more suitable shape but have not succeeded.

$$a-b\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}=\frac{\frac{a^2}bx+ay-cx-dy}{\frac a b x+y}$$

I have also tried to go about it by considering the general rules for adding and multiplying  rational and irrational numbers, like rational * irrational = irrational and such. But this also did not seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Hint: Show that their sum is irrational (which takes some work), hence at least one of them is irrational.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah, this is an approach I haven't even thought of. After adding the two terms though I can only infer that the solution might have something to do with the $a+b$ and $a-b$ of which at least one definitely has to be irrational. Do you know that this method can get one to a complete proof? Because I still seem stuck. I also don't know if I should just think of the fraction as one variable or consider each one of its components, which seems harder but might be the only way to prove the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. The choices $a = \frac13 (2 + \sqrt2)$, $b = \frac13 (1 - 2 \sqrt2)$, $c = \sqrt2 - \frac23$, $d = 0$, $x = 1$, and $y = 1$, for which $\dfrac{cx+dy}{ax+by}=\sqrt2$, yield $b+a\dfrac{cx+dy}{ax+by} = 1$ and $a-b\dfrac{cx+dy}{ax+by} = 2$.

*Brainstorming*: the specific form $z=\dfrac{cx+dy}{ax+by}$ is a red herring—since $c$ and $d$ can be arbitrary real numbers, $z$ can be an arbitrary irrational number regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. So we're essentially asking whether one of $b+az$ and $a-bz$ must be irrational if $a$, $b$, and $z$ are all irrational. This seems unlikely, though, since we have three degrees of freedom and only two counterexample-constraints to meet.

For a specific example, let's try to solve the equations $b+az=1$ and $a-bz=2$ for $a$ and $b$: we obtain $a = \dfrac{z+2}{z^2+1}$ and $b = \dfrac{-2z+1}{z^2+1}$. Choosing $z=\sqrt2$ (a random simple irrational number) makes $a=\frac13(2+\sqrt2)$ and $b=\frac13(1-2\sqrt2)$ also irrational.

Finally, there are lots of ways to make $\dfrac{cx+dy}{ax+by}=\sqrt2$: for example, we can just take $x=y=1$ and $d=0$ for simplicity, and solving yields $c=\sqrt2-\frac23$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I wasn't sure before if the fraction can be any irrational number for specific a and b. But with this counter example it is also obvious that the claim is false. Thank you.